# How to merge specific property names and concatenate theirs values upon certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, mapping, reduce

I've got this type of dataset :

```
[
  {
    CODMAT: '86        ',
    LIBMAT: 'Chariot N.50 Damien           ',
    CODCAR: 'I050DCHE  ',
    ZONLST: 'A',
    ALLLST: 1,
    CIRMAT1: 'AUA',
    CIRMAT2: 'SUC',
    CIRMAT3: 'SAL',
    CIRMAT4: 'AU3',
    CIRMAT5: '   ',
    CIRMAT6: '   '
  },
  {
   ...
  }
]
```

I would like to concatenate all the '**CIRMAT**' data and delete these which are empty, like this :

```
  {
    CODMAT: '86        ',
    LIBMAT: 'Chariot N.50 Damien           ',
    CODCAR: 'I050DCHE  ',
    ZONLST: 'A',
    ALLLST: 1,
    CIRMAT: ['AUA','SUC','SAL','AU3']
  }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What problem are you having? You can use `for (let key in object)` to loop over the keys. You can use `key.startsWith('CIRMAT')` to tell if it's one of the `CIRMATx` keys. Then you can push the value onto another list that will become the combined `CIRMAT` property.

Comment: I don't know how to create a new key, then put all the others into it and most of all delete all of the empty strings. I mean, I'm not asking for nothing.

Comment: SO isn't a tutoring service, you're expected to learn the basics on your own, and then we help you fix your code.

Comment: Related: [Iterating through a badly designed API where object keys consist of text and numbers](/q/49835981/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```js
    const data = [
      {
        CODMAT: '86        ',
        LIBMAT: 'Chariot N.50 Damien           ',
        CODCAR: 'I050DCHE  ',
        ZONLST: 'A',
        ALLLST: 1,
        CIRMAT1: 'AUA',
        CIRMAT2: 'SUC',
        CIRMAT3: 'SAL',
        CIRMAT4: 'AU3',
        CIRMAT5: '   ',
        CIRMAT6: '   '
      },
    ]

    const output = input.map(item => (
      Object.entries(item).reduce((formatted, [key, value]) => {
        if(key.startsWith("CIRMAT") && typeof value === "string"){
          if(value.trim().length === 0) return formatted;
          if(!formated.CIRMAT) formatted.CIRMAT = [value];
          else formatted.CIRMAT.push(value); 
        }
        else{
          formatted[key] = value;
        }
        return formatted;
      }, {})
    ))
```

Comment: @qgbdqrbqdrg ... Doesn't this work just for a `CIRMAT` based (numbered) property name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) together to achieve what you want.

Checking for an *empty* string happens by using [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) which removes leading and trailing whitespace from the string and then checking the length of the string.

```js
const input = [
  {
    CODMAT: '86        ',
    LIBMAT: 'Chariot N.50 Damien           ',
    CODCAR: 'I050DCHE  ',
    ZONLST: 'A',
    ALLLST: 1,
    CIRMAT1: 'AUA',
    CIRMAT2: 'SUC',
    CIRMAT3: 'SAL',
    CIRMAT4: 'AU3',
    CIRMAT5: '   ',
    CIRMAT6: '   '
  },
]

const output = input.map(item => (
  Object.entries(item).reduce((newObj, [key, value]) => {
    if(key.startsWith("CIRMAT") && typeof value === "string"){
      // ignore values that are "empty"
      if(value.trim().length === 0) return newObj;
      if(!newObj.CIRMAT) newObj.CIRMAT = [value];
      else newObj.CIRMAT.push(value); 
    }
    else{
      // just assign the same key the same value
      newObj[key] = value;
    }
    return newObj;
  }, {})
))

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

1. `map()` is required to map each value in the `input` array 1:1 to a value in the `output` array.
2. `reduce()` will do the transformation of a single item within the array. If the `key` starts with `CIRMAT` we need to check whether we already have a `CIRMAT` property on our working object `newObj`. If we have not, this is the first `CIRMATx` property and we need to create an array containing the `value`. If we already have an array and just need `push()` the new `value` to it. In case the key does not start with `CIRMAT` we just add the `value` and `key` to our working object `newObj` without any changes.

Comment: Doesn't this exclude any other numbered key which has a name base distinct from `CIRMAT`?

Comment: Not really following. It would not exlude a property `a1`, `a2` etc. if that's what you mean. It wouldn't accumulate those values, sure, but that's not what OP asked for and they would still be in the resulting object. Is that what you mean? Or could you give me an example of when an exclusion happens?

Comment: You're right, I meant excluding from being merged and concatenated. I was thinking more generic in terms of merging any property names of following naming pattern ... _digit-less (leading) substring followed by digit-only (trailing) substring_.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly not a uniform/ generic solution, but specific to this use case it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

An approach which covers the naming schema of any to be merged `key`/property name generically needs to go through all of an item's entries (key-value pairs) where it would separate each `key` into its digit-less normalized property name and its digit only suffix (the trailing number) part. Then it would merge/collect only entries which feature both, the new `key` and the to be discarded `number` where in addition the `value` is not empty (or just a whitespace sequence).

Thus one might use ...

- a regex like ... `/^(\D+)(\d+)?$/` ... which matches the pattern of a digit-less leading string and a digit-only trailing string where both substrings are being captured.
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to create a new array of changed/merged items.
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in order to get the key-value pairs of each to be mapped array item.
- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in order to process (merge and/or collect) each entry of the to be mapped array item.

```js
function mergeEquallyNamedButNumberedEntries(item) {
  const regXNumberedKey = /^(\D+)(\d+)?$/;

  return Object
    .entries(item)
    .reduce((merger, [key, value]) => {

      const [
        match,
        mergerKey = null,
        trailingNumber = null,
      ] =
        key.match(regXNumberedKey) ?? [];

      if (mergerKey !== null) {
        if (trailingNumber !== null) {
          if (String(value ?? null).trim() !== '') {

            (merger[mergerKey] ??= []).push(value);
          }
        } else {
          merger[mergerKey] = value;
        }
      }
      return merger;

    }, {});
}

const sampleData = [{
  CODMAT: '86        ',
  LIBMAT: 'Chariot N.50 Damien           ',
  CODCAR: 'I050DCHE  ',
  ZONLST: 'A',
  ALLLST: 1,
  CIRMAT1: 'AUA',
  CIRMAT2: 'SUC',
  CIRMAT3: 'SAL',
  CIRMAT4: 'AU3',
  CIRMAT5: '   ',
  CIRMAT6: '   '
}, {
  foo: 567,
  bar: 'baz',
  baz99: '  ',
  baz88: ' ',
  baz77: '',
  biz11: '',
  biz22: ' ',
  biz33: 'foo', 
}];

const result = sampleData
  .map(mergeEquallyNamedButNumberedEntries);

console.log({ result, sampleData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```